# oracle next_day function to use day number

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
     l_d NUMBER;
     l_day VARCHAR2(3);
     l_new_day date;
BEGIN
SELECT my_day
INTO l_d
FROM ...
WHERE id = ...; --results as 2 (monday)

l_day := CASE l_d 
          WHEN 1 THEN 'SUN'
          WHEN 2 THEN 'MON'
          WHEN 3 THEN 'TUE'
          WHEN 4 THEN 'WED'
          WHEN 5 THEN 'THU'
          WHEN 6 THEN 'FRI'
          WHEN 7 THEN 'SAT'
         END ;
     l_new_day := next_day( sysdate, l_day);
END;
```

Do we have any simple method without using that `CASE` part?
Thanks for any help in advance ;)

Comment: next_day(sysdate,l_d) would do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to find the day name, just do it simply with the day number like,

```
SQL> SELECT next_day( sysdate, 2) FROM DUAL;

NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE,2
------------------
20-JAN-14
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this query can help you:

```
Select to_char(sysdate, 'DY') FROM dual;
```